# Generate random variables from a probability distribution

Tags: python, numpy, math, random, normal-distribution

I have extracted some variables from my python data set and I want to generate a larger data set from the distributions I have. The problem is that I am trying to introduce some variability to the new data set while maintaining the similar behaviour. This is an example of my extracted data that consists of 400 observations:

```
Value    Observation Count     Ratio of Entries
1        352                    0.88
2        28                     0.07
3        8                      0.02
4        4                      0.01
7        4                      0.01
13       4                      0.01
```

Now I am trying to use this information to generate a similar dataset with 2,000 observations. I am aware of the `numpy.random.choice` and the `random.choice` functions, but I do not want to use the exact same distributions. Instead I would like to generate random variables (the values column) based from the distribution but with more variability. An example of how I want my larger data set to look like:

```
Value         Observation Count        Ratio of Entries
1             1763                     0.8815
2             151                      0.0755
3             32                       0.0160
4             19                       0.0095
5             10                       0.0050
6             8                        0.0040
7             2                        0.0010
8             4                        0.0020
9             2                        0.0010
10            3                        0.0015
11            1                        0.0005
12            1                        0.0005
13            1                        0.0005
14            2                        0.0010
15            1                        0.0005
```

So the new distribution is something that could be estimated if I fitted my original data with an exponential decay function, however, I am not interested in continuous variables. How do I get around this and is there a particular or mathematical method relevant to what I am trying to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you want to generate data based on the PDF described in the second table. The PDF is something like

```
0 for x <= B
A*exp(-A*(x-B)) for x > B
```

`A` defines the width of your distribution, which will always be normalized to have an area of 1. `B` is the horizontal offset, which is zero in your case. You can make it an integer distribution by binning with `ceil`.

The CDF of a normalized decaying exponential is `1 - exp(-A*(x-B))`. Generally, a simple way to make a custom distribution is to generate uniform numbers and map them through the CDF.

Fortunately, you won't have to do that, since [`scipy.stats.expon`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.expon.html) already provides the implementation you are looking for. All you have to do is fit to the data in your last column to get `A` (`B` is clearly zero). You can easily do this with [`curve_fit`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.curve_fit.html). Keep in mind that `A` maps to `1.0/scale` in scipy PDF language.

Here is some sample code. I've added an extra layer of complexity here by computing the integral of the objective function from `n-1` to `n` for integer inputs, taking the binning into account for you when doing the fit.

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit
from scipy.stats import expon

def model(x, a):
    return np.exp(-a * (x - 1)) - exp(-a * x)
    #Alternnative:
    # return -np.diff(np.exp(-a * np.concatenate(([x[0] - 1], x))))

x = np.arange(1, 16)
p = np.array([0.8815, 0.0755, ..., 0.0010, 0.0005])
a = curve_fit(model, x, p, 0.01)
samples = np.ceil(expon.rvs(scale=1/a, size=2000)).astype(int)
samples[samples == 0] = 1
data = np.bincount(samples)[1:]
```

Comment: In my case I have no knowledge of the PDF in the second table, but instead it is what I am expecting based on my initial data. Therefore, I replaced the data in your answer with the distributions of the first table.
`x=[1, 2, 3, 4, 7, 13]` --
`p=[0.88, 0.07, 0.02, 0.01, 0.01, 0.01]`
Also there was a problem with the code matching scalars with vectors so I modified the following lines:
`a = curve_fit(np.vectorize(model), x, p, 0.01)` --
`samples = np.ceil(expon.rvs(scale=1/a[0],  size = 2000)).astype(int)`
There is no need for `np.vectorize()` for the alternative model.

Comment: @Turtle. Sounds good. I'd say `np.vectorize` is a terrible solution for anything in this context. Better actually fix the cause of the error. What's the error?

Comment: The generated out put is what I would expect if I use an exponential decay function, but is there a way to introduce more variability in the output? Currently, the output distribution is something like: `values=[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]` and `counts=[1781, 185, 30, 3, 1]` but I would like to have that stretched across a wider range of values, say `[1, 2, .., 15]`, if there is a function that could do that while maintaining the a distribution similar to the one of the first table.

Comment: the original error was `TypeError: only size-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars`

Comment: @Turtle. The whole point of a PDF is that its the probablility of a *random* distribution.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/210157/discussion-between-turtle-and-mad-physicist).

Answer (score 2):

If you have an exponential decay, the underlying discrete probability distribution is a [geometric distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_distribution). (It's the discrete counterpart of the continuous [exponential distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_distribution).) Such a geometric distribution uses a parameter `p` with the probability of success of one trial (like a biased coin toss). The distribution describes the number of trials needed to get one success.

The expected mean of the distribution is `1/p`. So, we can calculate the mean of the observations to estimate `p`.

The function forms part of scipy as [`scipy.stats.geom`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.geom.html). To sample the distribution, use `geom.rvs(estimated_p, size=2000)`.

Here is some code to demonstrate the approach:

```py
from scipy.stats import geom
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from collections import defaultdict

observation_index = [1, 2, 3, 4, 7, 13]
observation_count = [352, 28, 8, 4, 4, 4]

observed_mean = sum([i * c for i, c in zip(observation_index, observation_count)]) / sum(observation_count)

estimated_p = 1 / observed_mean
print('observed_mean:', observed_mean)
print('estimated p:', estimated_p)

generated_values = geom.rvs(estimated_p, size=2000)
generated_dict = defaultdict(int)
for v in generated_values:
    generated_dict[v] += 1
generated_index = sorted(list (generated_dict.keys()))
generated_count = [generated_dict [i] for i in  generated_index]
print(generated_index)
print(generated_count)
```

Output:

```
observed_mean: 1.32
estimated p: 0.7575757575757576
new random sample:
    [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 7]
    [1516, 365, 86, 26, 6, 1]
```